# what is POOl in lease line i got 30 wan

Tags: lan, wan, optical

Please help me

**Proposed IP Pool**

**WAN/30 & LAN/29** what is the meaning how computers usable for this connection.this lease line connection optical fiber

Comment: Unless you add details to your scenario and the specific problem nobody will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but I believe this means they will allocate two blocks of public IPs.

A /30 block will be used to address the connection between you and your ISP. This will leave one usable IP for the ISP-facing interface of your router.

A /29 block will be routed to your router for addressing a network behind your router. A /29 has 8 IPs but if you do things in the conventional way then two of these IPs will be used for network and broadcast and one will be used for the internal interface of your router leaving 5 usable for machines behind the router with public IPs. These can be used for any internet-facing servers you want to run.

For client machines you should be able to employ NAT to support large numbers of machines.